# Scala Play2 Error on Web Service call

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm getting an error on compile with the following code.
I'm trying to call a Web Service.

```
def authenticate(username: String, password: String): String = {
    val request: Future[Response] = 
      WS.url(XXConstants.URL_GetTicket)
          .withTimeout(5000)
          .post( Map("username" -> Seq(username), "password" -> Seq(password) ) )            
      request map { response => 
        Ok(response.xml.text)
      } recover {
        case t: TimeoutException => 
          RequestTimeout(t.getMessage)
        case e =>
          ServiceUnavailable(e.getMessage)
      }

}
```

I'm seeing the following compiler error:

```
 type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[String]] required: String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value being returned from your `authenticate` function is `val request = ...` which is of type `Future[Response]` but the function expects a `String` which as the compiler says is a type mismatch error. Changing the return type of the function to `Future[Response]` or converting `request` to a `String` before returning it should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Like say Brian, you're currently returning a `Future[String]`, when you method said that you want to return a `String`.

The request return a `Future` because it's an asynchronous call.

So, you have two alternatives:

1. Change your method definition to return a `Future[String]`, and manage this future in another method (with `.map()`)
2. Force the request to get this result **immediately**, in a synchronous way. It's not a very good deal, but sometimes it's the simplest solution.

   ```
   import scala.concurrent.Await
   import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
   val response: String = Await.result(req, Duration.Inf)
   ```